# plotting quarter wise using ggplot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot display the data set quarter-wise, but when I am using following command it is not in proper order i.e. the plot is in alphabetical order rather than the sequence given in the data.

```
ggplot(data =b1[b1$Rank==2,], aes(x=Quarter, y=Max, group=1)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Here is the data:

```
 Max    Quarter     Rank

25379   Jul-Sep'13  2 
25012   Oct-Dec'13  2
25026   Jan-Mar'14  2
24821   Apr-Jun'14  2
24946   Jul-Sep'14  2
24423   Oct-Dec'14  2
23738   Jan-Mar'15  2
23562   Apr-Jun'15  2
23122   Jul-Sep'15  2
22227   Oct-Dec'15  2
22347   Jan-Mar'16  2
21558   Apr-Jun'16  2
21272   Jul-Sep'16  2
23109   Oct-Dec'16  2
22349   Jan-Mar'17  2
```

I have also tried to use the unique() function.

```
b1$Quarter <- factor(b1$Quarter, levels =unique (b1$Quarter))
```

But the plot is still not in order.

Comment: `b1$Quarter <- factor(b1$Quarter, levels =unique (b1$Quarter))` should work

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you turn the dataframe into a `ts` object recognizing that this is quarterly data and then plot it using `autoplot()`?

```
y <- ts(df$Max, frequency=4, start = c(2013, 3)) ##starting 3rd Quarter
autoplot(y)
```